# Javascript variables sent to modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, datatable

I have PHP code that spits out an HTML table. In this row, I have an input type=\"checkbox\" that sends the id=\"$Row[ID_NUMBER]}\" to a modal window. Here is the echo statement that prints the row data with the checkbox.  Take notice of the extra data field in the row.

```
 echo "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{$Row[ID_NUMBER]}\" data-info=\"{$Row[BOL_NUMBER]}\" name=\"checkMr[]\" /></td></tr>";
```

Here is the javascript the retrieves the id=\"{$Row[ID_NUMBER]}\" and displays it in the modal window:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function modalForm(){
     $('a').click(function modalForm(){
     var selectedID = [];
     $(':checkbox[name="checkMr[]"]:checked').each (function modalForm(){
       selectedID.push(this.id);
     });
     $(".modal-body #idNumber").val( selectedID );
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Of course there is a button that calls the javascript function via onclick="modalForm();" that I don't think I need to show you.  However, here is where the modal prints the #idNumber:

```
 <label>Container Selected</label>
 <input disabled type="text" name="idNumber" id="idNumber" placeholder="no containers selected" />
```

What I need to do on top of retrieving the id from the datatable is retrieve the data-info=\"{$Row[BOL_NUMBER]}\" and send it to the modal window.  I have an input field for boNumber that goes right underneath idNumber:

```
 <label>Bol Selected</label>
 <input type="text" name="bolNumber" id="bolNumber" />
```

I know this can be done within the same javascript function above.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(':checkbox[name="checkMr[]"]:checked').each (function modalForm(){    
    selectedID.push(this.id);
    // get the data-info from checkbox and set value in modal
    $("#bolNumber").val($(this).attr('data-info')); 
});
```

Comment: I really have no idea what you are doing with modalForm since you are redeclaring it several times. If you want to use the function drop the function keyword.

Comment: I have multiple modal windows and I figured I will need to utilize several javascript functions.

Comment: Should there be another section in the javascript that sends the 'data-info' to a section in the modal?